# The circuit, especially 7 segment parts does not work at all

Tags: breadboard, 7segmentdisplay

[image]

I made a circuit of experiment 19 from *Make : Electronics 2nd Edition.* It's called "time transitor."

I made the first part of this circuit by referring the upper pictures, but when I connect the electricity, it does not work at all.

I want to figure out what's wrong with it.

[image]

Comment: Please link to the original project to see the schematics. We can't possibly know from the picture what the circuit is supposed to do or how things should be connected, not to mention we can't even see what those chips are.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The upper one is 555 timer, the second one is 4026B chip, and the last one is 7 segment device. I'm really sorry for the broken English.

Comment: That's not a very good tutorial, for example the single resistor on the LED display is poor design.  Anyway start at the output and work back, see if you can light a segment bypassing the 4026B, then get the 4026B to display anything at all, then get the 555 clocking it.  Are you sure you have the right display and have not mixed up common anode with the needed common cathode?  And show your power source.  Buy a voltmeter if you do not have one and check key points in the circuit.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the answer. If you don't mind, can you give me some feedbacks online.. for example like by using zoom to see directly what's wrong with my advice. Because, I don't major in electronics, I'm almost illiterate about the circuit...

Answer (score 5):

I see one thing that looks wrong.

[image]

See the break in the blue line on the breadboard? That means that there is not a connection between that line and where you connected the ground. You have to jumper over it if you want it connected.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I'm not sure what the red point is....

Comment: The resistor is not connected to ground, so no LEDs light.

Comment: It's connected... Do you think there's nothing wrong on that circuit of the picture from the book I posted on this website?

Comment: @WrightMark try moving the resistor lead on the right up the line 3 holes. Let us know how you go

Comment: Can you please give me some feedbacks online by chatting or something else..?

Answer (score 5):

The breadboard power line is physically disconnected between the gaps. Add a jumper cable as indicated in the picture below (red line).
[image]

Comment: Staples work too, often enough you want the blue and red lines to be continuous powerlines on breadboard anyway. Doesn't fall out as easily.